# Change tt_content's TCA for a subtype?

Tags: plugins, types, typo3

Is it possible, for a specific plugin (e.g. `newspage_pi1`), to configure its TCA, i.e. its back-end form display? Just for that specific plugin, because when changing `tt_content`'s TCA for the `list` type (i.e. plugins) like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']["list"] = [
    'showitem' => "
  (tabs..palettes..columns..etc...)"];
```

It changes it for all plugins, and I only want to change it for the `newspage_pi1` `list_type`.

Yes, I know that I can use `'subtype_value_field' => 'list_type'` and then `subtypes_excludelist` and `subtypes_addlist` to add or remove fields for specific plugins. But this is not nearly as powerful as setting `showitem` directly, since it allows to define new tabs, palettes, position the fields how you want to, etc.

I also know about [FlexForms](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/FlexForms/Index.html), but these only control the `Plugin Options` field, not all the other ones.

Is there a way to change the `showitem` for a specific plugin?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Yes, of course and it's quite well documented: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Index.html

Comment: @biesior Thanks for responding. But the thing is that all the examples there change the `showitem` field for a `type`, which is not what I want to do. For a plugin (`tt_content` table), the type is always `list`. The thing is that I want to change the `showitem` field for the `list_type` subtype, i.e. for a specific plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly said, what you actually want is not a subtype but another type, since it needs to change fields other than the usual plugin / pi_flexform configurations.

So instead of adding that subtype as a plugin you should add it as another CType to get the full power of `showitem`.

Basically, this is how we add any kind of plugin too, since it makes more sense to have real database fields at hand instead of faking them with XML data structures.

As mentioned in the description here https://api.typo3.org/master/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html#ab4f6c66990aca246eac5390a76f0c83c

> ... - or more generally use this function to add an entry to any
> selectorbox/radio-button set in the FormEngine

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I understand, adding the new plugin as a new `CType` instead of a new subtype of the `list` type enables us to use the full power of the TCA `showitem` instead of just using `FlexForms`.

My question would now be: what would you recommend for adding new configuration fields to the plugin (e.g. which "articles" from the storage page to display in my "news page")? A new field on `tt_content`, or using FlexForms, or even using a reference from `tt_content` to a new table specifically created for the plugin? I do the latter for my custom content elements.

Comment: Also, now when creating a an instance of that plugin, I get the error of: `Content Element with uid "283" and type "newspage_pi1" has no rendering definition`. Because, since it is not a content element, but a plugin, I didn't create the typical TypoScript configuration for it, e.g. : `tt_content { ...newspage_pi1 { templateName = NewsPage ...` Since I want to use the Controller  and Actions and all the Plugin workflow, not a Template, as it were a custom Content Element.

Comment: See my comment on your other question regarding the TS configuration.

My recommendation for additional fields would always be a real DB field and a TCA configuration, since FlexForms date back to a time, where it would have caused serious performance issues to add fields to a table.

Then again having XML in the database creates other performance issues und makes it close to impossible to search for values of those fields. So the drawbacks outweigh the advantages. If you still want to make use of FlexForms you should use them for configurational values only, not for content.

Comment: I see. I also want to avoid FlexForms since for debugging and changing the database they are a mess. My only problem now is that, as you see: on one hand I want to register the plugin as a new CType, so I can change its `showitems` property (so its being treated like a custom CE). On the other hand I also want it to still behave as a Plugin, so load its first action defined with `configurePlugin` instead of directly loading a Template.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs this, TCA custom manipulation can also be done with [FormDataProviders](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/FormEngine/DataCompiling/Index.html)

Here's an example:

In myext/**ext_localconf.php** register a new FormDataProvider in order to manipulate custom CTA keys.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['formEngine']['formDataGroup']['tcaDatabaseRecord']
[\Vendor\Myext\Backend\FormDataProvider\PluginFlexFormManipulation::class] = [
    'depends' => [
        \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormDataProvider\TcaFlexPrepare::class,
    ],
    'before' => [
        \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormDataProvider\TcaFlexProcess::class,
    ],
];
```

In myext/Classes/Backend/FormDataProvider/**PluginFlexFormManipulation.php**

You can do your own TCA processing here and debug/check the $result array to see what's possible.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Myext\Backend\FormDataProvider;

use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormDataProviderInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ArrayUtility;

/**
 * Allows TCA column override per plugin list_type.
 */
class PluginFlexFormManipulation implements FormDataProviderInterface
{
    // Can use a shorter key here, depending on your needs or not use a constant at all.
    public const LIST_TYPE_COL_OVERRIDES = 'myext__overrideColumns_list_type';


    public function addData(array $result)
    {
        if ($result['tableName'] !== 'tt_content' || $result['databaseRow']['CType'] !== 'list') {
            return $result;
        }

        $currentListType = $result['databaseRow']['list_type'];
        foreach ($result['processedTca']['columns'] as $fieldName => $tcaFieldConf) {
            if (!isset($tcaFieldConf[self::LIST_TYPE_COL_OVERRIDES])) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!isset($tcaFieldConf[self::LIST_TYPE_COL_OVERRIDES][$currentListType])) {
                continue;
            }

            // Override TCA config from defined list type colOverride TCA config.
            ArrayUtility::mergeRecursiveWithOverrule(
                $result['processedTca']['columns'][$fieldName],
                $tcaFieldConf[self::LIST_TYPE_COL_OVERRIDES][$currentListType]
            );

        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

In myext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/**tt_content.php**

```
use Vendor\Myext\Backend\FormDataProvider\PluginFlexFormManipulation;

// Add onChange => reload to the myplugin_type plugin pages field.
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['columnsOverrides']['pages'][PluginFlexFormManipulation::LIST_TYPE_COL_OVERRIDES]['myplugin_type']
    = ['onChange' => 'reload'];
```